# How to refer to different kind of resources in pub?

Tags: resources, dart, dart-pub

In `pubspec.yaml`, we can refer to an dependency resource by specify the version. But how to refer to other kind of resources?

e.g.

1. a git repository
2. a local directory
3. a local .zip file
4. a local .tar.gz file
5. a http url
6. a svn repository

I can't find documents for them.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Git packages](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#git-packages)
2. [Path packages](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages)
3. not possible
4. not possible
5. not possible
6. not possible

Answer (score 2):

**GIT**

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
```

Specific branch:

```
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
      ref: some-branch
```

**Local path**

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

**Everything else**

Not possible at the moment.

Source: [Pub documentation](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html)

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the other answers, referring to a http url (#5) is possible so long as the server is a pub package server:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    hosted:
      name: transmogrify
      url: http://your-package-server.com
    version: '>=0.4.0 <1.0.0'
```

You can run your own pub server by using the [open-sourced pub code](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang). You can also find more information on the [Google Group dicussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/WhbrAlBIQvQ).